# Why does DateTime.ToString not give timezone as expected

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

If I have this code:

```
                DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
                string sDate = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zz");
```

my sDate looks like this:

```
"2013-04-07 21:05:15.396 +10"
```

which is the current UTC datetime (9:05pm), but with a "+10" on the end which is my local timezone.

I would have expected this:

```
"2013-04-07 21:05:15.396 +00"
```

what's going on?

Comment: Look at the DateKind property.

Comment: Kind is UTC, which is what I would expect since I've called DateTime.UtcNow

Comment: @frenchie `UtcNow` always sets `Kind` to `DateKind.Utc`

Comment: @PeterRitchie: ok, good to know. Just posted that comment cause I thought it might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zzSpecifier) says (emphasis mine):

> With `DateTime` values, the "zz" custom format specifier **represents the
>   signed offset of the local operating system's time zone from UTC,
>   measured in hours. It does not reflect the value of an instance's
>   `DateTimeKind` property.** For this reason, the "zz" format specifier is
>   not recommended for use with `DateTime` values.

So, the `zz` format specifier always outputs the UTC offset of your local timezone, even when used to format UTC times.

Comment: thanks, that looks like the answer. That seems very counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.ToString`, when you don't pass a `CultureInfo` into it, defaults to the current culture.  If your current culture is +10, then that explains why you see +10.  There's various FxCop and Code Analysis rules you can turn on to warn you when you call `ToString` without a `CultureInfo`